# dynamic increment step to define a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I would like to know is there anyway to do the following statement in matlab?

```
10: 2to power(1,2,3):18
```

I want to create the following vector and I need to have a dynamic increment step which is 2 to the power of (1,2,3).

```
a=[10,12,14,18]
```

I tried

```
 10:2.^[1,2,3]:18
```

and

```
 10:2.^[1;2;3]:18
```

but it takes 2^1 as increment step.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot have a dynamic increment value in MATLAB.

The MATLAB way of doing this would be to create the array `2.^[1 2 3]` and add it to the `10` and concatenate that with `10` to construct your vector.

```
a = [10 10 + (2.^[1 2 3])]

% 10  12  14  18
```

If you wanted, you could write a function to create these arrays.

```
function out = pow2increment(start_value, end_value)
    % Figure out how many powers of 2 we need for this range
    upper_limit = floor(log2(end_value - start_value));

    % Construct the array
    out = [start_value, start_value + 2.^(1:upper_limit)];
end
```

Or as an anonymous function

```
pow2increment = @(a,b)[a, a + 2.^(1:floor(log2(b - a)))];

pow2increment(10, 18)

% 10  12  14  18
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Definitely there are easier ways to create this vector. I wanted to know whether there is something like it in matlab or not.

Comment: @user6276336 Updated to be more explicit. There is not a way, but I've offered two functions that can create these types of series for you.